# Audio recording from mic in flutter web returning wrong mime type in safari

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to record the user's audio from mic in Safari using flutter web but when i print mime type for recorded base64 it is returning application/octet-stream how can record it as mp3, wav or webm.

I have tried applying mime type to the Blob but it is also not working.